# Como soluciono el error al importar una imagen en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Cita en bloque
> Attempted import error: 'imageSimpsons' is not exported from
> '../images/image1.svg' (imported as 'imageSimpsons'). ERROR in
> ./src/components/NavMenu.jsx 159:15-28 export 'imageSimpsons'
> (imported as 'imageSimpsons') was not found in '../images/image1.svg'
> (possible exports: ReactComponent, default)

```
introducir el código aquí

import {imageSimpsons} from '../images/image1.svg'
<img src={imageSimpsons} alt="" />
```

Comment: Cual es el problema con poner directamente `<img src="../images/image1.svg" />`? Porque el import no puedes usarlo así para eso. Cuando haces un `import {loquesea} from 'archivo'` necesitas que el archivo tenga un `exports loquesea = ...`, y un svg obviamente no va a tener una declaración `exports` de JS.

Answer (score 1):

Quita las llaves `{}` de la importación.

```
import imageSimpsons from '../images/image1.svg'
<img src={imageSimpsons} alt="" />
```